# Eject Circuit Board From Jig

Tags: mechanical-engineering, 3d-printing

I have a jig I am working on that accepts a circuit board. When the lever is pressed I would like the board to be ejected to the left - as shown in the image.

What I am finding is that the board is ejected directly upwards.

I have tried different shapes and length of arm to try and control this with no success. Does anyone know of modifications I can make to control the direction?

Requirements:

When the circuit board is installed it must be parallel to the table. I.e. I can't rotate the entire jig.

When the circuit board is installed there can't be any obstructions directly above the board.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You need 2 levers.  One to lift left side.   Second to move board sideways to left.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The first lever can also have a second lower finger to flip the second lever.

Comment: With @StainlessSteelRat's approach, you might also want some fences to guide the ejection path

Comment: This is poorly defined.  What do you mean "Eject to the left"?  Will a human operate this?  Is there a target somewhere they are aiming for?  How far does it have to go?  What is the expected final state?  Circuit board 20cm to the left?  With the board facing down?  Or up?  Does it have to land on something?  In something?  Does someone just need to get a finger under it to pick it up?  How is it loaded?  Can you accept a lip opposite the lever?

Comment: @J... I am looking for general advice. I can fine tune it later...

Comment: @Andy This is a specific problem - there is no such thing as general advice.  Either the solution effectively solves your problem (which we don't know what it is yet) or it doesn't.  Basic mechanics dictates how things move, so the general advice should be obvious.  If you want it to rotate you need to produce a torque.  Presumably, if you're a mechanical engineer, you should understand this already so we have to guess that you're getting stuck on something else - for reasons we don't know because you haven't told us.  What are your constraints?  Objectives?

Comment: I am not a mechanical engineer, so how to do this is not obvious to me. Thankfully with 3D printing I can rapidly prototype and test but so far not much success.  It seems the springs are having an undesirable effect on the direction. I think the problem is fairly clear from the question but thanks for replying.

Comment: @Andy How about a simpler question then - why is it bad that it ejects straight up? I can imagine a dozen scenarios where that would be perfectly fine and a dozen others where it might not be.  Each of them I would propose a different solution to, though, because for each of them it could be bad for entirely different reasons.  It's incredibly difficult to propose solutions without understanding what the problem is - you have all of that information in your head but haven't written it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a small tab next to the lever with a 45 degree angled face towards the board. Found by trial and error this appears enough to consistently guide the board away from the lever instead of doing backflips directly upwards.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your lever is applying force to the approximate center of the board. It's not perfectly in the center and I suspect that the contact is such that the board ejects not quite vertically, but enough to be other than your desired trajectory.

It would be necessary to remove the bulk of the ejection block, leaving the portion nearest the lever. Alternatively, the pivot for the lever should be moved to the right, which would also displace the ejection block to the right. With the new contact location, the board would be lifted from the right side first, especially with the single retaining spring on that side, compared to the pair on the left.

Comment: That's likely to flip it to the left, which may or may not be desirable and is likely to be quite sensitive to how quickly the lever is pushed

Comment: I've given it a try and the ejection force is now less but it tends to want to eject over the lever to the right.